# GIS tool for creating lines between points according order numbers by tracing a bus line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, route

I need a GIS tool for automatically creating line objects between bus-stop points according to the order numbers of bus-stop points by tracing a bus route line which coincides these bus-stop points. 
Point to Line tool in ArcGIS is not for me because this tool directly creates a line between points. But I want this created line object to trace the bus route though. On the other hand created lines will be according to the point order. So there can be overlapping line objects at the end. Because points locations are not ordered (not placed according to the order).
There are many tools to create line between points but none of them allow tracing a line.

[image: Click here for a sample:]

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is that the points that comprise a bus route are not ordered.  But what about the arrival time at each point?  Select one bus "run" from beginning to end of the route.  That collection of time values would act as a surrogate for point order, start to finish.

Comment: It's unlikely a specialized tool like this exists, but you could certainly attempt to build one, then work the issues as you encounter them.

Comment: Do you have the Network Analyst extension?

Comment: @Stu Smith: I mean points are not located ordered but point's order numbers are on their attribute table.  Arrival times are absent.

Comment: @Vince: Thank you Vince

Comment: @PolyGeo: I have Network Analyst extension but there is not a tool for my purpose in it.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.